# How do I fix [Root element is missing]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using vspro 2015 and when I open my project it says  The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.  C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\bitTemp\bitTemp\bitTemp.csproj

How do I fix this?

Comment: by opening your project you mean opening the`.sln` file?
`bitTemp` is your own project ?

Comment: Open the .csproj file in a text editor and compare it to one that works.  It may be the xml declaration that's missing, or the project node (root element) could be incorrect for some reason.

Comment: @Scorix-yes that's the name of the project

Comment: @Scorix-the  csproj file is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blank `.csproj` is never going to work. Something has deleted all its content and it either needs to be recovered or re-created.

The best route is to recover from your version control system (VCS) (git, or whatever you use), this might also give you the ability to workout when/who cleared it out. From a backup is also possible.

Otherwise you'll need to re-create.

Delete the empty file, create a new project (this might need to be in a new folder, at least until you get the project created), then add all the files and settings to it you had before. (This is why a VCS is a really really really good idea even for trivial test projects.)